# Keep taxonomy base name in post permalinks

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting

I have a custom taxonomy (I'll call 'issues' in this example) registered as such:

```
register_taxonomy('issues',array('post', 'pieces'), array(
    ...
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'issues',  'with_front' => true, ),
    ...
));
```

This works how I like and sends the archive page for each term to `www.example.com/issues/january/`. Next I want posts within this taxonomy term to show up as `www.example.com/issues/january/post-name/`

However, I've tried many different forms of rewrites and filters and have so far only managed to get the permalinks to be `www.example.com/january/post-name` but I would prefer to keep the taxonomy base name (`/issues/`) in the URL as it is for the taxonomy archives. I have gone into Settings>Permalinks and added `%issues%` to the Custom Structure (and I also make sure to flush permalinks every single time I make a change). Below is the filter rule I have currently:

```
add_filter('post_link', 'issues_post_permalink', 10, 3);
function issues_post_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($permalink, '%issues%') === FALSE) return $permalink;
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    if (!$post) return $permalink;
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'issues');
    $term_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
    return str_replace('%issues%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

If I try adding `issues/%issues%` to the Custom Structure that also does not work, though I am not sure why. I think I am missing some sort of rewrite rule, but I've tried to adapt a few from other threads and they don't seem to work. Most of the other 'guides' and threads involve a custom post type and I 'd prefer to not have to add one of those if possible.

Comment: Is your taxonomy hierarchical? The difficulty is probably that if it is, then if you went to `/issues/january/first/` WordPress won't know whether `first` is a post or a child term of `january`.

Comment: that works! I never thought the hierarchy was causing the issue. I changed that to `false` and updated the Custom Structure to `/issues/%issues%/` and it now displays correctly.

The only concern I have now is that I hard-coded the `/issues/` base into the custom structures, which may cause problems if I want a post without this taxonomy.